# System.Drawing.Icon constructor throwing "Operation completed successfully" exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, icons, system.drawing

On a Windows XP machine, the following code is throwing a System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception with the message "The operation completed successfully"

```
System.Drawing.Icon icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("icon.ico");
```

I can stop the program crashing with

```
try
{
    System.Drawing.Icon icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("icon.ico");
}
catch(System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.NativeErrorCode != 0)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

but of course the icon is not set.

The full stack trace is

```
at System.Drawing.Icon.Initialize(Int32 width, Int32 height)
at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor(String fileName, Int32 width, Int32 height)
at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor(String fileName)
at hermes.Window1..ctor() in D:\\projects\\hermesclient\\hermesWPF\\hermes\\Window1.xaml.cs:line 50"
```

That line 50 is the original line I posted.

This is a WPF app, and on a Windows 7 machine the code works fine.

EDIT: Turned out the icon wasn't working in Windows XP at all, adding 256 colour versions seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the icon wasn't working in Windows XP at all, adding 256 colour versions seems to have fixed it.

Comment: This unfortunately is not a fix for me. Having the same issue with Windows 7 and Windows 10. Adding image with 256 colors did nothing to help.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it the problem seems to be an issue with not disposing with objects properly. It's hard to pin point exactly where the issue in your case is occurring but as a general rule of thumb make sure you implement the `using` directive when dealing with objects that implement `IDisposable`.

Even in the sample you have provided try doing something like:

```
using (var icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("icon.ico"))
{
    // use icon
}
// icon is then disposed.
```

Have a read of this [article](http://nomagichere.blogspot.com/2008/03/systemcomponentmodelwin32exception-is.html).

Comment: This wasn't the problem, the icon was just broken, but this will almost certainly save us a headache later on!

Answer (score 1):

Does the file `icon1.ico` exists in the same directory as the .NET executable? You did not say explicitly...are you reading this as an external icon file? perhaps this

```
string sPath2Icon = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "icon1.ico");
using (System.Drawing.Icon icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(sPath2Icon)){
    // Do what you have to do with icon!
}
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. in my case the icon file was a multiicon file containing 32x32, 48x48 and 256x256 size icons. I changed it to a single icon file size 32x32 and it worked fine after that.