# TargetInvocationException when using Resources

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-2.0

I seem to be having some issues using resources in my solution at present. I'm getting a TargetInvocationException in a couple of places where there really should be any errors...

Own code:

> commands.Add(new AddDatabaseItemCommand(setting,
>   IconResources.DatabaseObject, this));

The DatabaseObject is an Icon, that is indeed contained in the IconResources.resx file and is set to "linked at compile time". This has been working for a few weeks without issue.

Designer generated code:

```
this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
```

Exactly the same problem, this is the Icon for a Form, and again is within the resources file "formName.resx" file as an Icon, placed there automatically by the designer. The options on this icon are "Embedded in .resx".

The InnerException even has the cheek to say "The operation completed successfully"!

Anyone have any idea what might be going on? My colleagues with the same code aren't have any issues...

Comment: Have you rebuilt your project?  It sounds like something got corrupted, and so wiping out your output and building fresh may solve this.

Comment: @davisoa: A few times now to no avail :(

Comment: That's too bad - it was worth a shot.  :)

Comment: Are you on the same OS as your colleagues? [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356580/system-drawing-icon-constructor-throwing-operation-completed-successfully-excep)   Also, can you open these icon files in VS?

Comment: @davisoa: Yep, we're all on the same OS, same version of VS. I can indeed open these files in VS.